# Size of images in imageview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an imageView inside a listView. Set up like this:
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:scaleType="center"    
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works great, filling in many images from url with http request. But I have a problem with the size of the images. I want them to fill the screen regardless the resolution or size. Tried with different layout hight, width and scaleType but cant get it to work properly.

First image is how it looks now, second image is how i want it to look.

EDIT: tried with scaleType="fitXY" that gave me 100% width, but a bad hight on the longer images.

[image: This is how it looks now]
[image: This is how i want it to look]

Comment: Any solution for ur prob ???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and didnt find another solution except making my own class.

```
public class Banner extends View {

private final Drawable mDrawable;

public Banner(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public Banner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public Banner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Banner, 0, 0);
    try {
        mDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.Banner_image);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
}

@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    if(mDrawable != null) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = width * mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

}
```

then add the attributes to some file in `/values` folder

```
<declare-styleable name="Banner">
    <attr name="image" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and use this new conrol like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:banner="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.project.name.here"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_ height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<your.project.name.here.Banner
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    banner:image="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

it will adjust height proportionally to the image width

Comment: Think this is they way to go yes, but cant get it to work properly. I'll try a bit more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NinePatch Images

[Link Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have used it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:scaleType="center"    
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this,i have change some:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:scaleType="FITXY"    
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

set fixed size of imageView,then scaleto FITXY. i hope the problem would be solved with this.

Comment: This gives med the same hight on every image, I want full width, and different height depending on image. Sorry if not clear enough on that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement. You should put your code like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"    
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` use `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"` and also in `java` file use :

```
yourImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```

If we use `android:src` it it sets the image according to its resolution to fit on the screen. And if we set the image as background, we can set in desired `width` and `height`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [android:adjustViewBounds="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds) and [android:scaleType="centerInside"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) on your image views.

Also, unless you're doing something else not shown in your question with the RelativeLayout in image.xml, it is pointless.